# Exception upon trimming the extension of key values of dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary with key values and I am trying to trim the extension of these values but get the exception message that item with same key has already been added.

Not sure why it is the case.

This is the code I used

How can I overcome this problem?

```
dictFilesNotThere = dictFilesNotThere.ToDictionary
            (t => t.Key.Remove(8, 3), t => t.Value);
```

The key value is as follow '7dim-058-ns' and I trying to get it to '7dim-058' instead

Comment: You need to formulate a new plan for potential key collisions; your plan of "hope there are none" is failing.

Comment: Also, do you actually perform lookups on your dictionary? If not, you might consider a `List<Tuple<string, int>>`, which would happily allow duplicate "keys".

Comment: `dictFilesNotThere.GroupBy(t => t.Key.Remove(8, 3)).Where(g => g.Count()>1).SelectMany(t => t.Key)` This query will show you the problem keys.

Comment: If you absolutely need to have dupe keys, consider looking at .ToLookup instead of .ToDictionary. In essence, a dictionary type structure that allows multiple items per key.

Comment: Last question: what is your purpose in this trimming, and why do you need the trimmed results in a dictionary? You've shown us a problem with your current solution, but I think we'd be of better help if you showed us the full problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have following items in the dictionary:

```
dictFilesNotThere.Add("7dim-058-ns", 1);
dictFilesNotThere.Add("7dim-058-n2", 2);
dictFilesNotThere.Add("7dim-058-n3", 2);
```

Then after removing via `t.Key.Remove(8, 3)` you will get: `7dim-058` as the key for all the above items. Since in the dictionary you can't have duplicate keys, that is why the exception.

To get rid of the problem, you can setup a `counter`  and add that to the key, if the key is found in the dictionary before. Something like:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictFilesNotThereCopy = new Dictionary<string, int>();
int counter = 0;
foreach (KeyValuePair<string,int> item in dictFilesNotThere)
{
    if (dictFilesNotThereCopy.ContainsKey(item.Key.Remove(8, 3)))
        dictFilesNotThereCopy.Add((item.Key.Remove(8, 3) + (counter++)).ToString(), item.Value);
    else
        dictFilesNotThereCopy.Add(item.Key.Remove(8, 3), item.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the same key already exists you have to specify which you want to keep, for example the first:

```
dictFilesNotThere.Select(kv => new { kv, newkey = kv.Key.Substring(0, 8) })
            .GroupBy(x => x.newkey)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First().kv.Value);
```